# How can I extract rows from table in SCALA corresponding to indexes present in a list.?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

Using Scala, I loaded a hive table into spark
This table has 3 columns and 10,000 rows. I also have this list:

```
List[Int] = List(43, 48, 353, 413, 645, 674, 764, 873, 1018, 1170, 1206, 1626)
```

I have to extract all the rows (with all the columns) from the table corresponding to elements present in the given list. How can I do that?
I need the final output in data frame format.

Comment: What is the meaning of this -  "Using Scala, I have a table with 3 columns and 10000 rows ?". There are no tables in Scala. Are you talking about Spark-SQL tables and Spark DataFrame?

Comment: Yes, I meant Spark-SQL tables and dataframe. I have obtained this table from dataframe only. Is it possible to fetch the required rows from dataframe itself ?

Answer (score -1):

```
val l = List(43, 48, 353, 413, 645, 674, 764, 873, 1018, 1170, 1206, 1626)
val table: Array[Array[T]] = ???
table.map(col => l.map(index => col(index)))
```

This will return the columns of `table`, but only with the rows you mentioned. Beware that this will throw some exception if you do not have at least `1627` rows.

This is assuming that your `table` is an `Array` whose elements are the columns. If it is an `Array[Row]`, you need to do the analog:

```
l.map(index => table(index))
```

Comment: Well... whoever down-voted this should have left a comment about it. @Cyrille please try to think more about the requirements before jumping to a solution with wrong assumptions about the problems statement.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Sorry about that. The question (and the assumptions I made about it) seemed clear to me, until they weren't. I edited my answer accordingly.